# Easy way to find import statement for a java package?

Tags: java, import

I have been using java for a while, and whenever I need to install a package, I generally just look online for an example or guess it. I have looked online for an answer to this question, and am surprised that it is only given in terms of the "name" of the package, the "name" of the subpackage, etc. But where do I find this info? Is there a place I can always look to find the import statement? If not, I am confused about why this is not done as it would be very easy and a huge timesaver.

For example, if I want to import the package "objectlabkit" in java, what is the import statement? I know that the name of the package is objectlabkit, and yet when I type this in followed by a ".", nothing shows up.

Any suggestions?

-Paul

Comment: well, I would expect some subpackages to show up after the "." As there are nearly always sub-packages/classes after the package name, this is generally how I can tell if I am starting the import statement correctly.

Comment: The thing is that I am not sure the name of the package really is "objectlabkit" -- that is what it is referred to by everyone, but I am not sure how to find out what the official name of the package is, i.e. how to start the import statement. And I have made sure the jar is added to the classpath, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you use e.g. Eclipse and if you type in `import java.` and wait say 1 sec,
then the sub-packages do show up. Just make sure that your package/lib's jar
is on the build classpath of your project i.e. that Eclipse knows about it.

Then the sub-packages will show up. Also, develop the habit to press `Ctrl` + `[space]`
from time to time. And ... if you use another IDE, it will have a similar feature for sure.

Comment: Peter, than you for your comment. The problem is that no subpackages are showing up, which tells me that I have the package name wrong. Where can I find the name of the package?

Comment: Google for `objectlabkit api docs` (provided that objectlabkit is the real name of this library you're going to use, and not just a sample name that you used for asking the question).

Comment: And ... also... if you have the jar file, you can always open it with say 7-zip and see what's inside. That's another way of knowing the packages stored in that jar/lib which you have downloaded and which you intend to use.

Comment: still not working. How exactly would that tell me the name of the package? Does the name of the file have to be the same of the name of the jar file?

Comment: @Paul The package name is `net.objectlab.kit` (see that link I posted above).

Comment: ok, it is working now. so in order to find that I should just look at the api docs?